# raw_query - update multiple colums - doesn't work with Idiorm

Tags: php, mysql, idiorm

I'm using [Idiorm](http://idiorm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/querying.html) - a very simplistic ORM. I'm trying to update multiple rows in a single query. Idiorm doesn't support this, so I'm left with either `n` queries or a [`raw_query`](http://idiorm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/querying.html#raw-queries) statement.

I choose the latter.

However, I can't seem to make it work. They query in itself isn't very complex:

```
UPDATE products 
SET discount_green = some_value 
WHERE category_id = some_other_value 
AND discount_green != yet_another_value
AND has_double_discount != 1
```

In Idiorm syntax it would look like this:

```
ORM::for_table('products')
        ->raw_query(
        "UPDATE products 
         SET discount_green = :some_value 
         WHERE category_id = :some_other_value  
         AND discount_green != :yet_another_value 
         AND has_double_discount != 1",

        array(
            'some_value' => $some_value,
            'some_other_value' => $some_other_value,
            'yet_another_value' => $yet_another_value,
        )
    );
```

The `for_table` param could very well be `NULL`.

I have tried:

1. Simply executing the query without binding the params  as in a whole complete query with static parameters - did not work
2. Using no ORM - works fine.
3. Using question marks instead of the `:` notation - doesn't work.

With that being said, I'm probably missing something obvious here. Any nudging in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

I have looked into options like `raw_execute`, didn't have much luck with that either.

It doesn't particularly matter, but all the values are numeric.

Comment: You could just simply debug it using [query logging](http://idiorm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#query-logging).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefer a single query, `raw_execute` is the way to go. You could do something like the following.

```
ORM::raw_execute("UPDATE products " .
                 "SET discount_green = :some_value  " .
                 "WHERE category_id = :some_other_value " .
                 "AND discount_green != :yet_another_value  " .
                 "AND has_double_discount != 1",
    array (
      "some_value" => $some_value,
      "some_other_value" => $some_other_value,
      "yet_another_value" => $yet_another_value
    )
);
```